# MySQLdb execute

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error, mysql-python

I have searched high and low on this site and many others and have found similar questions, but none of the answers have worked for me (usually just accounting for the tuple). I'm writing a python script to parse html pages and populate a database. I have almost everything working except the populating part...

Here is the code segment that deals with the mySQL database (note: using MySQLdb module in python)

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="xxxxx",db="nutrients")
cur = conn.cursor()
test = "Canned Corn"
cur.execute("INSERT INTO food (name) VALUES (%s)", (test,))
conn.commit()
```

I was first testing it with parsed string but that wasn't working. This gives me 2 errors:

1. Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 171, in execute
       r = self._query(query)
     File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 330, in _query
       rowcount = self._do_query(q)
     File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 294, in _do_query
       db.query(q)
   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax
   ; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right s
   yntax to use near '%s)' at line 1")
2. Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 171, in execute
       r = self._query(query)
     File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 330, in _query
       rowcount = self._do_query(q)
     File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 294, in _do_query
       db.query(q)
   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax
   ; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right s
   yntax to use near '%s)' at line 1")

Why does this query not work!?

---

Update: After nearly pulling my hair out I decided to revert back to 2.7.3 and guess what... everything works now :D Should have know it was an error of that type... Thanks for the help none the less everyone!

Comment: @user145896 is name the only column that you have in your table?

Comment: Maybe try to cat the string inside as follows: str = "INSERT INTO food (name) VALUES" + test and then cur.execute(str)

Comment: @jcho360 no it's not, but I though you could just specify 1 column and the data in SQL

Comment: The problems seems to be not in the SQL syntax itself, but in that `%s` isn't really substituted with the value of `test`.

Comment: Are you sure you execute the exact same code that you show? This error could happen if you forgot to pass `(test,)` as the second argument to `execute` or if you have another `%s` in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need any tricky or advanced SQL; you just need to store and retrieve some stuff.  So, I think an ORM might make life a lot easier for you.

I suggest you try using the Autumn ORM:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/autumn/0.5.1

That is a small and simple ORM, easy to understand and work with.

Another good and popular ORM for Python is SQLAlchemy:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, tried SQLAlchemy and got literally the same error. I liked sqlalchemy so I am using it now :)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across this too. After a lot of digging around, this was found to work (note the change to values):

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="xxxxx",db="nutrients")
cur = conn.cursor()
test = "Canned Corn"
cur.execute("INSERT INTO food (name) VALUES ({0})", (test,))
conn.commit()
```

Background info: In the port of MySQLdb to Python 3 posted on an [unofficial Python packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) site, the execute function in cursors.py was modified to use format() rather than the % operator. Hence why %s remains in the SQL statement rather than being substituted. It looks like these changes were never upstreamed to the [official source](http://mysql-python.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/mysql-python/MySQLdb-2.0/log/566baac88764/MySQLdb/cursors.py).

Answer (score -3):

You should write your code like this :

```
 conn = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="xxxxx",db="nutrients")
 cur = conn.cursor()
 test = "Canned Corn"
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO food (name) VALUES (%s)" % (test,) )
 conn.commit()
```

If you are new to python and have some programming experience , then follow [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) book. Its free.

Comment: Doesn't using % lead to sql injections?

Comment: Why are you so much afraid of sql injection.Its yout databse and you are using it for yourself(I hope so).
ANd if sql injection can be applied here then , why not in your code using comma ???

Comment: @Manish - Ummm, you should *always* try to protect against SQL injections.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot : I know but i didnt get how % is more prone to sql injection and not , using syntax.

Comment: @Manish - `cur.execute()` escapes MySQL special characters before formatting. `%` and `''.format()` don't know a thing about MySQL special characters.

Comment: While it's better to think about sanitizing SQL fragments rather than exercising injection paranoia, the larger error here is that use of `%` does not leverage MySQL-specific escaping.